# Web scraper unable to click pagination button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using selenium and geckodriver (on Firefox) to scrape eBay. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

I just want to click the next button! What am I doing wrong? I've commented the two instances of button assignment that aren't working...

```
# import libraries
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd 
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

# specify the url

urlpage = 'https://www.ebay.com/b/Nike-Athletic-Apparel-for-Women/185082/bn_648725?rt=nc&LH_Sold=1' 
print(urlpage)

# run firefox webdriver from executable path of your choice 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# get web page
driver.get(urlpage)


for page_num in range(0, 2):
    parentElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name("s-item")
    results = parentElement.find_elements_by_css_selector("*") # all children by CSS
    #button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ebayui-pagination__control') # not working
    #button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/section[1]/div[2]/nav/a[2]/span/svg[2]/use') # not working
    button.click()

    print('Number of results', len(results))
    for r in results:
        print(r.text)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.head()
df.to_csv('eBay_scrape.csv')

driver.quit()
```

Error received:

```
https://www.ebay.com/b/Nike-Athletic-Apparel-for-Women/185082/bn_648725?rt=nc&LH_Sold=1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-58b4e0e554fc> in <module>
     19     #results = parentElement.find_elements_by_tag_name("li") # not working...
     20     #results = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("vip") # 50 results per page. But useless...
---> 21     button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ebayui-pagination__control')
     22     #button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/section[1]/div[2]/nav/a[2]/span/svg[2]/use')

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: And by "not working" you mean what exactly?

Comment: @FiddleStix - added the error message above. I'm rather new at scraping so I expect my lack of experience shows above.

Comment: I think that the `find_elements()` functions return a list and `find_element()` functions return a single value or raise an error if one cannot be found.  Therefore, you may want `button = driver.find_elements_by_somehow('something')[0]` or `button=driver.find_element_by_somehow('something)`. I would recommend using a debugger for this kind of thing because you would quickly have seen that a list was being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ebayui-pagination__control')` returns a list

there are 2 buttons with that class on that page - to check, type this in the Firefox console: `$$('.ebayui-pagination__control')`

so you need:
`button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ebayui-pagination__control')[1]` to get the second button.

The second approach (find_elements_by_xpath) looks super brittle with that long xpath, all it takes is for one array to change in that path and it will no longer work even if you do get it to work at first.

Comment: This works beautifully. I agree re: xpath and I'm glad this seems to work, for now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking the next page button by code, you could just update your scraping url.

If you notice, `&_pgn=<page_number>` gets appended to the url string for the subsequent pages. You could simply scrape a page and increment the page number until there's no valid page number left.

Answer (score 0):

You can induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` and following `xpath`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='ebayui-pagination__control'][@rel='next']"))).click()
```